# I'm not clear exactly how "overview" questions work

Tags: discussion, overview-questions

I edited @LCIII's [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30551/how-similar-was-the-resurrected-body-of-jesus-to-his-physical-human-body) to try and get it taken off hold. The response to my accepted edit was that the question was much better, but was still too broad.

I was specifically trying to follow guidelines from [this Meta question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/inquiring-perspectives-on-one-matter-from-throughout-all-of-the-christianity-spe) regarding "overview" questions; I was trying to limit the inquiry to a few broad outlines of the sorts of beliefs that are usually held by several major groups of denominations.

Have I misunderstood how "overview" questions work? Perhaps I'm missing something? This is an interesting question, and I'd like to get it to a point where it's off hold, gives @LCIII the credit he deserves, and returns some really good answers. Is that possible?

Comment: FWIW I just cast the final reopen vote even though I  was the one who said it was probably too broad.  I was really on the fence and kind of wanted to reopen but didn't want to do it unilaterally.  Three  others thought it was worth reopening after you edits.  I voted to reopen based on a combination of group consensus that it looked good. AND the fact that you made a good point with this question.

Comment: I still think this question needs an answer from the community.  I personally have a hard time deciding what's too broad on this type of question.

Comment: Hence the question :-) I'd love to publicize this question so people might be brought to answer it.

Comment: @MattGutting [This](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/q/3670/49) question is highly related, and might have some further guidance

Comment: Thanks! Can someone guide me to a **successful** summary/overview question? If not, should overview questions be considered specifically off-topic (I don't believe they are right now)?

Comment: @Matt [My answer here](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/16190/what-were-the-nephilim-and-what-role-did-they-play-in-the-bible-beyond-just-bei/16192#16192) would fit well in a question that asks "What is an overview of the varying views on this?" That question however, is actually close to Bible Trivia, and I honestly think it only remained open because my answer was so through. Sometimes an answer does justify the question.

Comment: @MattGutting [This one asks for an overview on a specific denomination.](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/16239/3961) That is close to this.

Answer (score 5):

[The top answer on that meta question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/871/3961) says right at the top:

> It is possible to ask for an overview of the beliefs of multiple traditions, **but you must specifically ask for this.**

You did not specifically ask for that! That's what you're missing!

I did not gather that it was an overview type question from what is there now. If that were in there I would be more receptive to calling it on-topic.

In general, you should make sure to use the word "overview" in the question. Likewise, I suggest you do the same for "Biblical Basis" questions. It helps clear up the confusion really quickly and tells any would be answerers what kind of answer you are looking for.