# Are overview questions on-topic?

Tags: discussion

[This question about an overview on matters 'after death'](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/81207/what-is-an-overview-of-christian-viewpoints-on-what-happens-to-humans-after-deat) prompted comments regarding overview, or 'survey' questions.

The 'on-topics' page states :

> However, there are questions that are not constructive for the format of this site. These include questions asking for:

> a survey of all Christian views on a particular subject

Is this the accepted status regarding such questions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've discussed this before, but not acted on it:

[What is meant by survey?](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6329/what-is-meant-by-survey)

I've now just changed the message to say "a straw poll of views on a particular subject".

Comment: Even the linked discussion and the [sublink](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/870/how-should-i-ask-overview-questions-on-one-matter-from-all-of-the-christian-spe) makes it sound like overview questions are hard to answer. We may be `site experts` but still knowing about a particular viewpoint by all Christian denominations (which is kind of still indeterminant) seems very broad. Even knowing 3 denominations viewpoints of the 'main' denominations may not cover the scope of Christian views. Is wiki answer the way to go for overview?

Comment: Here is an [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/56020/how-many-christian-denominations-are-there) where I attempted answering how many Christian denominations there are. If we're going to allow overview questions that ask for main Christian denominations can we define on the tour what main denominations an answer should touch on (unless a question states otherwise) when asking for an overview?

Comment: sorry if I've missed interpreted your answer, are you saying overview questions are ok just not straw polls?

Comment: @depperm Yes overview questions are great! Though they are indeed hard to answer. The usual thing I say is that they should aim to cover Catholicism, Eastern Orthodox, Oriental Orthodox, Protestant (possibly with Arminian, Reformed, Baptist, Pentecostal, etc sub-sections if relevant), LDS, JW. Collaborative answers would be great, though we're yet to really work out the practical ways to do it well.

Comment: I would think a "straw poll" would be more like "what denominations believe in consubstantiation?" - FWIW, I think those kinds of questions are more useful and answerable than overview questions.

Comment: @PeterTurner Those questions are fine (with the tag [tag:denomination-survey]). For a straw poll I was really thinking of the questions we get that ask for individual opinions: "What do you think happens when we die?"