# Would this be considered an example of an overview question?

Tags: discussion, editing, overview-questions, allowed-answers

I was watching [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/59335/32750) today to see how it would be treated. I was not confident, however, in attempting to answer it.

I think it would be a fairly easy question to answer, at least from my particular view; it seems pretty straightforward. I would have answered it, very nearly, the same way in which @anonymouswho answered it there.

In [this answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/871/32750), accepted by the OP, addressing [this question](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/q/870/32750) about the proper way to ask an overview question; I read this:

> 1. It is possible to ask for an overview of the beliefs of multiple traditions, but you must specifically ask for this.
> 2. If you would like an overview of what the possible positions are you must specifically ask for that.

This is what made me wonder, in the first place, how this question would be handled.

Reading the question the first time through, left the impression that this must be an overview question; what else would one think? Ultimately I decided that it was too risky to attempt an answer to the question; Also, I didn't know how to help improve the question, other than the typical 'ask this from viewpoints and particulars'.

So, is the question a good example of an overview question? If not, what might have been suggested to make it so; or to tip it toward a specific view?

Comment: I understood it to be a Biblical Reference question. You should provide an answer though. I'm pretty sure once the OP reads through my footsnotes they'll no longer accept my answer.

Comment: @anonymouswho I think you have answered the question. I doubt that I could add anything.