# Guidance to ask "an overview of the main Christian arguments about X" question which not necessarily align to a denomination / tradition

Tags: discussion, overview-questions

I think [this overview question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/92150/10672) asking "What is an overview of the **main arguments** that angels do or do not already exist at Genesis 1:1" is fine although it is not explicitly asking an overview of denominational positions.

#### Example from outside SE

By adding enough details to the question we can expect an answer to contain no more than 5 views.  We have literally dozens of this type of questions answered in book format such as [Zondervan's 38 volume Counterpoints Library](https://zondervanacademic.com/products/category/counter-points) and [IVP Academic's 22 volume Spectrum Multiview Book Series](https://www.ivpress.com/spectrum-multiview-book-series).  The views in these books are not always cleanly divided among denominational lines either.

#### How is it different than questions about denominational positions?

It's different since

1. "main arguments" don't depend on *authority* speaking for a denomination, or a theologian speaking on behalf of a *theological tradition*.
2. "main arguments" implies an emphasis on **the argument itself**: an informed theological speculation not necessarily backed by authority, but prominent enough in circulation.  Things like "concentric cessationism", "inclusivism", "sacraments as means of grace", etc.
3. the boundary separating the arguments is based on criteria *intrinsic* in the argument itself, not on sociological factor of who's accepting which argument
4. the sociological boundary of the arguments can cross denominational boundary, either **spanning** (like charismatic movement) or **splitting** (like baptism within the Reformed tradition)

#### Previous discussion on Overview questions

This meta question can then supplement [Caleb's answer](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/871/10672) on "How should I ask overview questions: on one matter from all of the Christian spectrum?" as Question type ④ :

> 4. What are the main Christian arguments about X?

#### The discussion question

My meta question is then:

1. **What is the official policy of asking this type of overview question**?
2. **How should the question be tagged?**  Do we reuse `comparative-christianity` and update the tag definition from

   > "comparisons of two or more denominations"

   to

   > "comparisons of two or more theological positions / denominations"

   or do we create another tag for overview question type ④?

Answer (score 0):

Tag it [systematic-theology](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/systematic-theology) question and I'll ignore it ever existed. Not [comparative-christiantiy](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-christiantiy), that is definitely about the differences between christian sects, as is [denomination-survey](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/denomination-survey).

But one can't ask a veiled "truth question" and disguise it this way.  Better to just ask multiple questions if you really want multiple viewpoints.

Specifically, I mean, what is the point of asking (which is what this technically is asking) What do they teach at CUA, Bob Jones and Brigham Young?  If anybody *knows* this answer - they're a genius. If anybody can find this answer, I doubt their sincerity.

I'd stick to "denominations" for overview and "theologians" for specifics.

Comment: I changed it from a specific question because a mod suggested changing it to an overview. Can the mods come to a concensus on this?

Comment: @one - probably not,  that's a [tag:biblical-basis] question, but it precludes knowing that there is a denomination that teaches that like Curiousdannii's saying.  In your case, I think you should ask "does anyone teach...."  Since a person can't just answer "yes" they'll need to explain themselves. So you'll get the answer.  The consensus of the mods is that we don't like overview questions, but we suggest them to help stay on topic and make objective answers where previously only "truth" answers would vie for the top spot.

Comment: Granted that [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/92150/10672) is not a good example.  That's why I provided sample questions published in the 2 book series.  Do you think the 38+22 questions a veiled "truth question"?  At any rate, it's prevalent enough to justify publishing a book about it.  In your opinion, can most of those questions be asked here?

Comment: @GratefulDisciple I'd imagine those books are great, I just don't know if we can get to that level on this site without a lot of discipline.    Reminds me of our old blog!  One of the reasons we started the blog was to do exactly this kind of a thing, present multiple viewpoints without stepping on each others toes.  It's just not Q&A, that's the problem.  Very vaguely it is, but I much prefer questions that can be succinctly answered.  I did like the crestomathy approach though.

Comment: I see.  So basically, the direction is to facilitate answers to be 1) narrower in scope (thus aversion to overview questions), 2) objective (not opinion), and 3) relevant (evidence of the view being seriously held in a Christian community, which implies the existence of enough revelatory/authoritative data to support it, not just pure speculation).  With these 3 criteria, questions like in the 2 book series really need a book-length answer, not a C.SE answer.